# How to use MIDI with the Java Sound API?

Tags: java, audio, midi, javasound

I try to implement a simple MIDI player with the Java soundAPI. I am new to Java, but not to MIDI programming. I have problems to understand the soundAPI correctly. What I want to do is to select a device, open it, send short MIDI messages to it and next close it. When using the SoundAPI one has to perform the actions described above, and added to that one has to grab a Transmitter and a Receiver, open the transmitter and send the message to its Receiver (is that right??)

I managed to get hold of the MIDI system and listing the properties of all available devices which is nice for a starter. I can open the device, but it throws the `MidiUnavailableException` exception when opening the Transmitter. I have summarized all steps which I have to follow in the function `send_simple_message` below. I have two questions:

- is my reasoning correct? I do not want to work with sequencers just yet, I now try to reconstruct a certain way of using MIDI to which I am accustomed to with the Windows API in Delphi which is: open the device, send messages to it and close it when ready
- if so, why an exception is thrown when I try to open a transmitter? This happens to all MIDI devices which I try to open

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
  public int send_simple_message (int device_no, int byte_1, int byte_2, int byte_3) throws InvalidMidiDataException
  {
     MidiDevice Current_Device; // Refers to MIDI device
     Transmitter Sender;        // its Transmitter
     Receiver Getter;           // the sender of the transmitter
     ShortMessage message;      // MIDI message to be sent to Receiver

     try 
     {  // Get requested device
        Current_Device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice (Device_Info [device_no]);
        System.out.println ("Selected: " + Current_Device.getDeviceInfo ().getName ());

        Current_Device.open();
        System.out.println ("Opened: " + Current_Device.getDeviceInfo ().getName ());

        Sender = Current_Device.getTransmitter (); // <== throws exception
        System.out.println ("Transmitter: " + Sender.toString ());

        Getter = Sender.getReceiver ();
        message = new ShortMessage (byte_1, byte_2, byte_3);
        Getter.send (message, -1);

        Sender.close ();
        Current_Device.close ();
     } catch (MidiUnavailableException e)
     {
        System.err.println ("MIDI device is unavailable");
        return MIDI_OPEN_NOT_AVAILABLE;
     } // try..catch
     return MIDI_ACTION_OK;
  } // send_simple_message //
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2)  It seems that if the first `try` fails, so will the 2nd & 3rd.  Why not put them all in one single `try` block?

Comment: @Andrew, good point. I abbreviated the code along your suggestions. The reason I use multiple `try` is that I could much better pinpoint the reason for the failure. For this example the `println`'s suffice.

Comment: *"..I abbreviated the code along your suggestions.."* `<head-desk />` 1) 'short' can typically be up to 150 LOC if all the code is needed to satisfy the rest. 2) The rest is not satisfied.